# Why are some string methods called with the variable inside the methods parentheses, and some outside?

Tags: python, string, methods

Why are some string methods called with the variable inside the methods parentheses, and some outside? e.g.

```
len(variable)  
variable.upper()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're confusing functions with methods.  A function call looks like:

```
func(arg1, arg2, ...)
```

A method call looks like:

```
obj.method(arg1, arg2, ...)
```

In your example, `len(variable)` is a call to the `len` function, which accepts several different argument types.  The call `variable.upper()` is a method call of the method `upper` for the object `variable`.

Comment: Thanks.. So this is what I now understand: functions are global, can be called on at least two data types, while methods can be called by only one. Methods are defined in a module or class (are they the same thing?), and use 'dot notation'.

Comment: Well, functions can be passed whatever argument type(s) they're written to expect.  Function arguments and method arguments are basically the same.  The only difference is methods have in instance of their class passed as the first argument (normally called `self`), and that argument precedes the method name in the call (followed by a dot).

Answer (score 1):

`len()`, `zip()`, `dict()` are examples of built-in python functions. `len()` is a function that returns the length (the number of items) of an object.

```
len([1,2,3])  # returns 3
len('abc')    # returns 3
```

`.upper()` is a method of the string module that formats a string to upper case.

```
str('abc').upper()  # returns 'ABC'
```

Comment: `str('abc').upper()` --> `str()` *function*  is useless here.